# How to install multiple odoo instances on the same machine

Tags: odoo

I want to have *more than one Odoo installation* on my machine (any platform is fine, whether Ubuntu, Windows 7, etc.), but I found it difficult how to do it. My main purpose is to develop Odoo for different purposes offline and then deploy them on the live server.

My question is that, is it possible at all to have more than one odoo installation on the same machine? If yes, how to?

My current solution is to use virtual box (or some similar pieces of software) and use only one installation per operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if you got the answer.
But this is what you can do:-

1. Replicate the files example in folders like odoo, odoo1.
2. Go to any of the folder and start odoo server using different port like pass `--xmlrpc-port=8000` in odoo folder and pass `--xmlrpc-port=8001` in odoo1 folder that will run two different instances of odoo with different code-base. Also you can pass `--dbfilter` to restrict limited database access per port.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into containers https://www.docker.com/. There are official docker images available here for Odoo: https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo/.

Each Odoo instance will run in its own container, and you can run multiple containers in parallel.